# Best way to use PDO in procedural environment

Tags: php, pdo

I just switched from MySQL to PDO and i am using prepared statements.

I used to have function for MySQL and on every page i did something like

```
$Query = "UPDATE users SET f_name={$POST["first_name"]}, l_name={$_POST["last_name"]} ";
$SQL_obj->runquery($query, "update");
```

Now with PDO and prepared statements does it make sense to create function as well or just do prepare(), bindValue() and execute() on every query?

I just cannot seem to write good PDO function. Can someone suggest? My code is mostly procedural.

Comment: You are referring to a `database abstraction layer`. Simply looking for a PDO based DAL should be all you need...

Comment: what is that second parameter, "update"? And what exactly you want from this function? Got a usage example? (I hope you're aware that you cannot use it the same way you used your runquery())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend PDO and add a helper method that does both:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO{

  public function prepareAndExecute($sql){

    // get all arguments passed to this function as an array
    $args = func_get_args();

    // drop first argument ($sql)
    array_shift($args);

    $stm = $this->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute($args);

    return $stm;
  }

}
```

Then:

```
$results = $connection->prepareAndExecute(
  'UPDATE users SET f_name=?, l_name=?', 
     $POST["first_name"],
     $_POST["last_name"]
);
```

(`$connection` = an instance of `MyPDO`)

Comment: great thanks, why function only has 1 argument and you pass 3 without fatal error?

Comment: That 1 argument is defined as required. Any other arguments that you pass are optional. `func_get_args()` will get you all arguments that the function has received

Answer (score 0):

PDO is allready a class, so its a little bit over kill to write a "wrapper" around it. Just use this way:

```
$Query = "UPDATE users SET f_name=:firstname, l_name=:lastname ";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($Query);
$sth->execute(array(':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'], ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname']));
```

You're example is vulnerable for injections.

Comment: typo ;). I think there is no need to use it driver options here.

Comment: I want to have 2 lines or 1 line instead of 3

Comment: @PetjaZaichikov here you go: `$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET f_name=?, l_name=?"); $sth->execute(array($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname']));`. 2 lines