# Why can't I connect to database using PHP Slim framework?

Tags: php, slim

I'm new to PHP Slim framework and I've written code to connect to database but it shows the following error in console (The database exists, still getting error):

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

function dbConnect(){
    $host='127.0.0.1';
    $user='root';
    $pass='';
    $dbname='testdbmysql';
    $pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname= $dbname", $user, $pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
}

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->post('/hello/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    echo "hello";
    $names = $request->getParsedBody();
    $db=dbConnect();
    $names_arr=[];
    $names_arr['name1']= filter_var($names['name1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $names_arr['name2']= filter_var($names['name2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello , ".$names_arr['name1']);
    $query=mysqli_prepare($db, "INSERT into info(fname, lname) VALUES(?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "ss", $names_arr['name1'], $names_arr['name2']);
    $result=mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
    $rows=mysqli_stmt_insert_id($query);
    echo "Rows: ".$rows;
    return $response;
});
$app->run();
?>
```

When I searched on Internet, I found solutions to same error caused by Laravel framework, but not about Slim. Is there something I can do?

Comment: What is unclear in message `Unknown database`?

Comment: I changed the databases and still same error. The database exists.

Comment: Try removing the space after dbname. `dbname=$dbname`

Comment: Well now my insert query is not working. PhpStorm shows this error in prepared satement: Expected mysqli, got PDO. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the whitespace

```
$pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
```

The error output is displaying the whitespace, too. So that should be the mistake.

Also, do not Mix up PDO and mysqli. You are passing a PDO-Connection to mqsqli functions, thats why you get " Expected mysqli, got PDO."

I would stick with mysqli and set up a connection via mysqli_connect().

Comment: Well now my insert query is not working. PhpStorm shows this error in prepared satement: Expected mysqli, got PDO. Any idea?

Comment: it wants you to use PHP's mysqli functions to connect to the db

Comment: Can't I use `mysqli_prepare()` ?

Comment: Well it would work. But it didn't answer my question. Can't I use prepare?

Comment: I dont get what you want to achieve with the use of mysqli_prepare to solve the Problem you got. But you are setting up a PDO-Connection to the DB and then using mysqli. I am not sure if its working that way

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO, dont mix them up http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Okay, I understand that now. Now when I searched for PDO prepare online, I got this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php This should work. But it is object oriented. Isn't there procedural way too, like mysqli_prepare has both object oriented and procedural ways?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200254/best-way-to-use-pdo-in-procedural-environment just dont. :P